# When using Many To Many Polymorphic Relations, can I retrieve all images and albums that share a tag?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Currently I'm using this to display all images that have a tag of $tagName:

```
$images = Image::whereHas('tags', function($q) use ($tagName) {
            return $q->where('name', $tagName);
        })->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
```

Now considering I'm using Many To Many Polymorphic Relations and I have these tables:

```
images
    id - integer
    name - string

albums
    id - integer
    name - string

tags
    id - integer
    name - string

taggables
    tag_id - integer
    taggable_id - integer
    taggable_type - string
```

Can I create a query that retrieves both the images and albums that have a tag of $tagName?

Comment: Do you want to get images and videos in a single query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can.

What gets stored in taggables is:

```
id = it's own primary key
tag_id = your custom foreign_key for tag id I'm guessing
taggable_type = model name     e.g.                       "App\Image"       
taggable_id = the model's id   e.g.                       "1"
```

Something among these lines, you can call from whatever model you'd want, depending on your needs and established relationships. It works just like any other relationship, all you need to know is that it finds the related model depending on the `taggables_type` and `taggables_id` and work them out

```
Taggables::whereHas('tags', function ($advancedWhereHas) use ($tagName){ 
       $advancedWhereHas->where('name',$tagName)->with(['relationshipToImages.relationshipOfAlbum']);
})->get();
```

Comment: That is strange, I don't even have a Taggables model, only Image, Album and Tag.

Comment: Your post above has a taggable model @Bobimaru

Comment: You can create a taggables model if you'd like. It's just a representation of a table in the form of a class. If not, you can get the same data from Image or Album or Tag, all you need to do is use the relationships to your advantage

Comment: I only have table taggables, without model since I haven't had the need for it so far.

Comment: You can have now :P with eagerloading from image, it would result in something like: Image::whereHas('tags', function ($q){ $q->with(['taggables','taggables.images','taggables.albums']]}).

Comment: One thing you should know is: The output the query gives is a bad standard to be an direct output to the UI. You should have methods or classes to work out responses

Comment: Do I have to set any relations in the taggables model? Currently I have morphedByMany relationship in my Tag for my images and albums and morphToMany in my Image and Album

Comment: Let's say you are Image and you access Taggables by relationship. Once you're in the With's eager loading, you are now in Taggables and need to access another relationship, therefore if you want to access via eloquent, yes, or you can write a function in the with's to get results from a certain table, and use querybuilder

Comment: Anything can be achieved via query. Think of queries as low-level thing. Eloquent is nothing more than a bunch of queries working together and applying logic to create the output in a form of a class, in a structured way. The example you wrote, Image::whereHas('tags'), in reality it is 2 queries: select * from images where exists (select * from tags)